# efficient bulk data insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have data in data log file in the following format.

Each line represent a row in the data base and there are 500-1000 rows to be inserted at a time.

Is is better to insert the data in the database directly by calling store procedure(the procedure contain the logic to call log file and insert data)

OR

Is it better to parse it in the application and insert data.

```
   29   2011-02-01 11:00:40 1   0   1   0
   30   2011-02-01 11:00:44 1   0   1   0
   32   2011-02-01 11:00:49 1   0   1   0
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is probably .tsv format (tab separated values).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'uniq.csv' INTO TABLE tbl
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
     ENCLOSED BY ''
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(column1, column2, column3)
```

\t is tab character. Change it for space if it doesnt work.

Manual processing row after row will be not efficient, because hard disk will be accessed many times when you try to read row by row. LOAD command should read whole file at once.

You should remember, that indexes can seriously slow down inserts like this. If you need to read a lot of data (100000 rows for example) - sometimes its better to drop index, insert, and re-create index after inserting.

Comment: But another problem is how do i access the file from database if the database and application are both hosted online

Comment: Dont you think it is better to create class and keep pre-processing logic in application instead of database

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use BCP (Bulk copy) command.

Import this log file in excel and save it as csv with separate column names.
Use the following syntax to import into tables in cmd prompt.

go to $\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn in cmd prompt

bcp in TableName "D:\logs\log.csv" -c -S Servername -U username -P password -t "," -r "\n"

you can alternatively specify -n instead of -c... 
-t :- comma seperated, -r :- Row terminator

Answer (score 0):

It is better (for performance) to insert data in bulk (using the LOAD FROM, or transactions. I am assuming store does something similar), than to insert them one at a time with a query per row.

Comment: Dont you think it is better to create class and keep pre-processing logic in application instead of database

Comment: The SQL server is likely has functions that are just as optimized as any code you write to preprocess it. In addition, it saves the round trip time between the server and the script. You can use the absolute path on the filesystem to access the file (assuming it is on the same server and has proper permissions). In the end, either works as long as you are using transactions, and for 500-1000 rows the performance difference is minimal between using the db directly or queries from a parsing script.

Comment: But how would to use the absolute path on the file system if you are hosting it online.

Comment: But how would you use the absolute path on the file system if you are hosting it online.